# Python Script Crashes When Using mayavi.mlab.mesh Function

Tags: python-2.7, crash, mesh, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am attempting to use the mesh function from the Mayavi mlab library - but every time I run the code, the program crashes.

The code I am running is just a slightly modified version of an example given in the documentation.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos
from mayavi import mlab

def main():

    PI = np.pi

    mlab.clf()
    phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:PI:11j, 0:2 * PI:11j]
    x = sin(phi) * cos(theta)
    y = sin(phi) * sin(theta)
    z = cos(phi)

    mlab.mesh(x, y, z, representation='wireframe', color=(0, 0, 0))

    mlab.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The program loads the Mayavi plot window and then  crashes with the following error:

- Process finished with exit code -1073741795 (0xC000001D)

I am using:

- Windows 7 Ultimate - 64 bit
- Anaconda 2 install for Python 2.7
- PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.1

I have tried other basic examples of code for mlab.mesh with the same results.

I have run other Mayavi scripts using mlab.plot3d without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of the representation='wireframe' fixes my issue. I.E.

```
mlab.mesh(x, y, z, color=(0, 0, 0))
```

The only "representation" that works fully is 'surface', which is default.

'mesh' and 'fancymesh' both work but produce warnings with the Mayavi interface.

'points' & 'wireframe' both crash python.

These representations are described in the documentation[[here]](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.mesh)